# Lost $100k (paper) money on property subdivision project. What should be my next step?

Tags: investing, real-estate, savings

I had the misfortune of working with a shady project manager for my first property subdivision project (1 property into 3). The development contract with him was for him to organise and supervise the subdivision for a price not more than $250k (including all works etc.) He promised that it would not cost as much, and he would only charge the actual cost and not the full contract price. Naive me accepted his promise. The project has since finished, and he is not forthcoming with the actual invoices from the contractors that he hired to do the work and has charged me the full amount.

I have invested $250k into this project but with resulting properties if I was to sell them all I would lose approximately $100k. The market values are slowly increasing and if I held onto the properties for 3-5 years at the current rate I would make that $100k back. However, I would be in a financially stressful state during those years (keeping up with mortgage payments taxes, etc). Should I sell it all now and end up with less money but less financial stress, or should I hold on in the hopes I will make it back?

Comment: This is probably a better question for the Law site, but I think the real problem here is that you forgot the old saying about verbal contracts not being worth the paper they're written on.  Unless you have a written contract saying that his charges would be based on costs, I would think you've just learned a costly lesson.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can not make that decision for you. We don't know what "financially stressful state" means for you. Would you have to switch to a cheaper brand of champagne? Or do you have to live in a cardboard box under a bridge? And even if we would know, we still wouldn't know if enduring that state for 3-5 years would be worth $100k *for you personally*.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: the contract said you would pay "not more than $250k", and he has charged you the agreed upon $250k, after verbal promises that he would charge you less?

Comment: It has been a costly lesson indeed. You raise a good point @Philipp, I will sit down and mull over the numbers and make a decision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am no expert but I did pick up on a couple flags to watch out for from your question. A key concept when making monetary decisions is to decide based on your goals and what you have NOW. Don't let the upset or disappointment for what has already happened cloud your judgement. Consider the property now, expected earnings, expected cost, expected risk, current situation and current means and make the best decision you can. If you need to sell your property, don't do it because you have already lost money from it and are scared. Sell it because you determined that was the best option from what is available.